# How do I get details for operation policies in Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-cli, azure-policy

Is there a way to filter out and get all of the policies for the operations in my APIM. I am working on a project that was taken over and is using lots of operations in APIM. Some of them have filtering for inbound IP and some don't. The whole idea is to filter all of the operations with some specific policy.

I am passing this line in AZ CLI:

```
az apim api operation show --resource-group $myResourceGroup --api-id $apiId --service-name $serviceName --operation-id $operationId
```

However for the policies field I get null as an output.

```
policies: null
```

I've also tested the *az apim api operation list* but I still don't get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the `operation ID` details using below CLI command.

```bash
az apim api operation show --api-id mynew --operation-id new -g xxx -n policyj
```

[image]

Once it is done, you need to use [`az rest --method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) CLI command with `Get` method to retrieve the policy details of API's as shown below.

```bash
az rest --method get --uri "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<APIM>/apis/<APIName>/operations/new/policies?api-version=2020-06-01-preview"
```

[image]